# Can a variable be associated to two different names?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Working in Google AppsScript, specifically for an add-on, and I'm defining the SHEET_NAME as a const. Specifically:

```
const SHEET_NAME="Values"
```

Since Google Sheets has a default name of "Sheet1" for all worksheets can I also make SHEET_NAME be associated to either "Values" or "Sheet1"?

Basically, if someone doesn't choose to name their file "Values" then the variable will still know to run SHEET_NAME without breaking.

Right now I have a function that is trying to use the SHEET_NAME variable, but again, trying to see if I can have it look for either "Values" or "Sheet1"

Is something like `const SHEET_NAME="Values" OR "Sheet1"` doable?

Comment: Please provide an example.  What you are saying doesn't make any sense to me "Sheet1" is a name of a Sheet Object and values are either a single string or number or a two dimensional array of strings or numbers

Comment: [javascript variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Variable)

Comment: "Values" in this case is the name of a worksheet.
"Sheet1" is the default name of a worksheet.
I would like a function that calls "SHEET_NAME" to still be able to run if someone forgets to rename "Sheet1" to "Values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just check if the `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName()` returns not null. If so you assign `value`:

```
const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
const SHEET_NAME = sheet1 ? "Sheet1" : "Value"
```

But in my country it is `Blad1` instead of `Sheet1` so i suggest rethink you're logic.

I would suggest something like this:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
let SHEET

const sheetCheck = ss.getSheetByName("TheSheetName")

if(sheetCheck){
  //Assign the founded sheet to the variable SHEET
  SHEET = sheetCheck
} else {
  //Create the sheet and assign to SHEET
  SHEET = ss.insertSheet("TheSheetName")
}

//Do something with SHEET
```

Comment: What if there are other worksheets and the default worksheet or Sheet1, Blad1, renamed Value are what I care about and not the other worksheets? The first worksheet basically is the worksheet that will have all the values vs. everything else will reference it.

Comment: I really have a hard time following your problem/question. Please unrattle the [x-y prblem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the active like this:

`const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`

This way, there is no need to meddle with sheet names. If you need the sheet name for some reason, you can get it like this:

`const sheetName = sheet.getName();`

When there are multiple tabs in the spreadsheet, you can get the sheet that shows first in the tab bar like this:

`const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];`